# Elasticsearh 8.8.0, runs yellow only and produces elastic_transport.ConnectionError when index is queried

Tags: python-3.x, authentication, elasticsearch

I am new to elasticsearch and much else and am trying to understand some things, please.

I am using python to start ES, index some .json, and am having some troubles.

Here is what I have done using:

MacOS Ventura, iterm2, brew, but primarily straight pip with terminal and python 3.9.

I have already checked for only 1 version of elasticsearch to avoid package confusion:

```
conda list | grep elasticsearch
pip list | grep elasticsearch
```

Then:

1 — lsof -i :9200 (make sure no instance of ES is already running).
2 — start up with a clean venv.
3 — deactivate all other env: conda deactivate.
4 — and pip install from my requirements.txt the following:

```
certifi==2023.5.7
elastic-transport==8.4.0
elasticsearch==8.8.0
psutil==5.9.5
urllib3==1.26.16
```

5 — I have a py script to start ES: it works and I can see ES has made it to YELLOW (but never green):

```
[2023-06-13T15:18:08,536][INFO ][o.e.c.r.a.AllocationService] [xxxxx.local]      current.health="YELLOW" message="Cluster health status changed from [RED] to [YELLOW] (reason: [shards started [[danocr-index][0], [.security-7][0]]])." previous.health="RED" reason="shards started [[danocr-index][0], [.security-7][0]]"
```

6 - I can run another py script to index some .json files and return the following if successful - it was successful, and I get this:

```
Indexed JSON file: /Users/aiki/Desktop/ocv/gcp_merged_json_out/wotw_02.json
Indexed JSON file: /Users/aiki/Desktop/ocv/gcp_merged_json_out/wp2021_01.json
Indexed JSON file: /Users/aiki/Desktop/ocv/gcp_merged_json_out/wotw_01.json
(gocr_env)
```

7 - I made another py script to query the index to make sure it has actually done something and get this:

```
elastic_transport.ConnectionError: Connection error caused by: ConnectionError(Connection  error caused by: ProtocolError(('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))))
```

(gocr_env)

So: I can initialize an ES instance that makes it to yellow (only, ever),
And I can index some json,
But cannot query that the indexing has worked properly (and so I have not even tried to get to the actual searching part yet, nor kibana, which is coming).

FYI, a manual check of https://localhost:9200 prompted username and password, which when entered, produced this:

```
{
  "name": "XXXX.local",
  "cluster_name": "elasticsearch",
  "cluster_uuid": "XXXX",
  "version": {
    "number": "8.8.0",
    "build_flavor": "default",
    "build_type": "tar",
    "build_hash": "XXXX",
    "build_date": "2023-05-23T17:16:07.179039820Z",
    "build_snapshot": false,
    "lucene_version": "9.6.0",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version": "7.17.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version": "7.0.0"
  },
  "tagline": "You Know, for Search"
}
```

The code for the py scripts are quite similar in approach, so am clueless here.

Questions please:

A — Why does the default install of Elasticserach server come with an http cert rather than https?  I am not getting errors now that I have set scheme to be https, but the cert itself says http. I do however see these cert directory files inside config:

```
http_ca.crt
http.p12
transport.p12`
```

How should I (should not) be using these three? Is my improper use of them the source of my error?

B — I can only assume that this: elastic_transport.ConnectionError: Connection error caused by: ConnectionError(Connection error caused by: ProtocolError(('Connection aborted.',

…refers to the http/https/auth issue/cert issues above?

C — I would think the maintainers of ES would provide everything necessary to make proper use of ES in the server download and pip installed packages (both versions of which match for me here, btw) and I am completely sure that they did, so it must be something I am missing and do not understand (that could be lots), and I think it is fundamental to the auth/http/https setup, but I am unsure where.

It is also (so) very possible I am asking the wrong questions entirely to get to the bottom of this, so any help right here, or pointers to specific documentation/tutorials would be very greatly appreciated.

Thanks to you all very much!